# Redemption: Error when creating first Redemption.SafeMailItem - missing OutlookServicing.dll

Tags: vb.net, outlook-redemption

I have a VB.Net application one function of which is to extract a list of the content of a shared mailbox and display that list in a grid. This has worked fine for years but we have recently upgraded a few accounts to Office 365 online and these accounts are now throwing up a message when accessing the mailbox for the first time. A cut-down version of the code follows:

```
Dim objOutlook As New Outlook.Application
Dim objNameSpace As Object = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Dim astrFolders() As String = Split(gstrDeptMailbox, "\")
Dim intCount As Integer = 0
Dim objFolder As Object = objNameSpace.Folders(astrFolders(0))
For intCount = 1 To astrFolders.GetUpperBound(0)
     objFolder = objFolder.Folders(astrFolders(intCount))
Next
Dim objMailItems As Object = objFolder.Items
objMailItems.Sort("ReceivedTime", True)
Dim astrColumns(5) As Object
Dim intRow As Integer
Dim objItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objSafeMail As New Redemption.SafeMailItem ' <-- Errors here
For Each objItem In objMailItems
    If Not objItem Is Nothing Then
        ' Blah
    End If
Next
```

The error message that pops up (not handled by me, seems to be coming straight from Redemption) is:

> The program can't start because OutlookServicing.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

This only happens the first time a SafeMailItem is created - after that everything works just fine - and after pressing OK on the message, the code continues as normal with no errors or failures; the mailbox content is extracted and displayed as usual.

Does anyone have any ideas what to do about this? The file OutlookServicing.dll is found at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16, which is where I would expect to find it in any case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OutlookServicing.dll is a an Office component responsible for checking for update etc.
Is reinstalling Office an option?

Comment: Hi Dmitry - thanks for the suggestion; I'll have a chat with our desktop support team and let you know how I get on. Cheers.

Comment: Hi again, Dmitry - it seems the problem may have been that Office 2010 was not uninstalled before the installation of Office 2016 and the new Exchange setup. I've got a request out for a clean rebuild of one of the test machines to see if that helps - fingers crossed.

Comment: Yes - reinstalling after removing uninstalling Office 2010 did the trick. As it happens, the users will all be getting new-build PCs with only 2016 installed anyway so problem resolved.